# Unable to Install Linux Mint on RAID

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, raid5, linuxmint

Second week now than I'm trying to setup Linux Mint on software RAID5 without success.

I'm able to setup the software RAID5 on the live CD with three 240GB SSD, then the installation setup fails to install the GRUB on /dev/sda

[Picture 1](https://plik.zsites.ca/file/eBQWm2XZYURbI1Ld/nYyLc6hbrTznBYgx/20220904-155701-RAID5_Setup.jpg)

Knowing that /dev/md0 is software thing, I do need to install GRUB on members disks, /dev/sda, b and
c but, I have this error:

[Picture 2](https://plik.zsites.ca/file/eBQWm2XZYURbI1Ld/1ynnpi9FRiCGBskf/20220904-160021-RAID5_Setup.jpg)

My motherboard is an Asus PRIME A520M-K and it is supporting hardware RAID up to RAID1, I
don't mind to use hardware RAID1 instead of software RAID5, knowing if someday the motherboard is dying I will need to restore the system from a Timeshift snapshot as the new hardware will break the RAID1.

Another issue is, Linux Mint live CD isn't recognizing the hardware RAID array. Is I need to provide a
driver? If yes, where to get it and how to easily install it?

I red several tutorials and I'm not able to find my solution.

Thank-you in advance for help.

Guillaume

Comment: Just a question like that, is I need to wait for the syncing get done before installing LM as well as the GRUB? May I install it on /dev/md0 in case of RAID1? But in case of software RAID5, where should I install the GRUB?

Comment: I still need help. If someone could help me.

Thank-you,